# Odd paging problem with DataGrid and sorting

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, datatable, filter, dataview

I have a data table that is being filled by a stored procedure.  I need to filter down the results some, so I get a data view from the default view and apply a row filter to it.  I then bind this to my DataGrid.  All is fine at this point.  I see two pages (17 records with 10 per page).  If i apply a sort to the grid though, it now shows 5 pages (58 records without the filter).  I stepped through the code and it repopulates the data prior to running the sort.  The repopulation is with with the filter in place and it counts 17 records, but shows 5 pages.

To make it even weirder, if I click on a page i know will be invalid, it runs the page change (which also repopulates the data) and this time it limits the pages to 2 and tells me i have an invalid page number!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It was the custom control causing the problem.  We have an AutoDataSource function that automatically pulls the data tables out of my view and sorts on them.  I found a filter function in my grid that apply the filter, but only if applied before setting the datasource

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to apply the sort to the default view and not the grid column directly.

Comment: I did.  I think it could be related to a custom version of the DataGrid we have internally.  we have something called a AutoDataSet and the sort runs off it.  It uses the dataset my dataview is created from.